# Count NA in multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to count the number of NA in multiple columns of my data. Here is a reproducible sample.

```
structure(list(V2QE38A = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), V2QE38B = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), V2QE38C = c(1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 
3, 1, 1), V2QE38D = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried two methods:
First one:

```
dt %>% select(starts_with("V2QE38")) %>% colSums(is.na(.))
```

And this gives me some results (in short, I have NAs in some columns)
Then I tried another one:

```
colSums(is.na(dt[,c("V2QE38A", "V2QE38B", "V2QE38C", "V2QE38D")]))
```

And I found no NA in any of these columns.

I think the second result is correct. But I'm just wondering what did I do wrong to get the first result? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, there are multiple functions passed.  We may either need to block it with `{}`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
    select(starts_with("V2QE38")) %>%
    {colSums(is.na(.))}
V2QE38A V2QE38B V2QE38C V2QE38D 
      0       0       0       0
```

or have another `%>%`

```
dt %>%
    select(starts_with("V2QE38")) %>%
    is.na %>%
    colSums
```

-output

```
V2QE38A V2QE38B V2QE38C V2QE38D 
      0       0       0       0
```

---

The issue is that `colSums` is executed first without evaluating the `is.na`

```
> dt %>% 
   select(starts_with("V2QE38")) %>% 
   colSums(.)
V2QE38A V2QE38B V2QE38C V2QE38D 
      6       1      12       0
```

which is the same as the OP's output with `colSums(is.na(.))`

Comment: I see! Thank you so much for the answer. Very clear!

Comment: @YYM17 By default, the first argument is taken from the lhs of `%>%`. the second argument of `colSums` is `na.rm` which is taken in `dt %>% select(starts_with("V2QE38")) %>% colSums(na.rm = is.na(.))`

Comment: Yep I just need to wait for another couple minutes to be allowed to accept the answer by the system Hahahaha

Comment: @YYM17 you can check these ` dt %>% select(starts_with("V2QE38")) %>% colSums(dims= is.na(.))
Error in colSums(., dims = is.na(.)) : invalid 'dims'` or `dt %>% select(starts_with("V2QE38")) %>% colSums(x= is.na(.))` wouldn't work as well because it already evaluated `x` from the lhs

Comment: Thank you! Seems that the logic behind colSums is a bit strange within pipe

Answer (score 1):

Base solution using `sapply` and an annonymous function `function(x){sum(is.na(x))}`:

```
data = structure(list(V2QE38A = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), V2QE38B = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), V2QE38C = c(1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 
3, 1, 1), V2QE38D = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

sapply(data, function(x){sum(is.na(x))})
# V2QE38A V2QE38B V2QE38C V2QE38D 
#       0       0       0       0
```

##### Explanation:

`sapply` applies a function on a `list`. `data.frame` is a list, with each vector being an item of this list. The `s` in `sapply` is for simplify, so `sapply` will try to convert the output list (from `lapply`) to a vector. If the required output is a list (it has some advantages), use `lapply` instead.

`is.na` returns a boolean `TRUE/FALSE` vector. This can be converted to a numeric vector with `1/0` values.

`sum` converts the `TRUE/FALSE` vector into a `1/0` vector and sums the values.

##### Alternative solutions:

Alternatively, instead of treating the `data.frame` as a list, treat it as a matrix. Then the highly optimized `rowSums` and `colSums` can come into play.

```
colSums(is.na(data))
# V2QE38A V2QE38B V2QE38C V2QE38D 
#       0       0       0       0 

rowSums(is.na(data))
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
# 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

This is great if you have a `matrix` and want to find where the `NA`s are.

Comment: Thank you! Before I tried ```apply``` though, but there are some issues when I was trying to combine it with ```dplyr```.It's good to know that ```sapply``` can be used instead!